# WalletConnect issue importing 'crypto'

Tags: reactjs, cryptojs, wallet-connect

I'm using wallet connect, but when I try to do the connect it gives me this error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'

And then it gives me this suggestions:

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
>
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:   resolve.fallback: {
>   "crypto": false }

I tryed but didn't work, somebody can help me?
The code of the connection is the same as how the website explain.
(I'm using React)

here more: https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/node

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue multiple times. This is because of `webpack` version 5 which introduces breaking changes. There are 2 solutions to this:-

1. Either follow what is written in [this](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/web3modal) article (make sure to install and add a fallback for `crypto` in the same manner as mentioned for others in this article).
2. Downgrade `react-scripts` from 5 to 4.0.3 and use with an LTS version of NodeJS.

Option 2 is easier and I would prefer it. In case you do too, follow these steps:

1. Run `npm uninstall react-scripts`.
2. Run `npm install react-scripts@4.0.3`.

Run `npm run start` to check if this works. If there is any error, delete the `node_modules` and then reinstall using `npm install` that should sort things out.